# Delete exclusive crashed queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

There is an exclusive queue. The application failed and did not close the connections correctly.

When app restarting, it tries to declare new queues, but there was already existing. I tried deleting these from web admin and rabbitadmin, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible delete exclusive crashed queue without deleted virtual host?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try this:

```sh
   rabbitmqctl eval '{ok, Q} = rabbit_amqqueue:lookup(rabbit_misc:r(<<"/">>, queue, <<"springCloudHystrixStream.anonymous.rq_ghYeMR7mbYJ8PzMyF8Q">>)), rabbit_amqqueue:delete_crashed(Q).'
```

Which `/` is your virtual host, and `springCloudHystrixStream.anonymous.rq_ghYeMR7mbYJ8PzMyF8Q` is your exclusive crashed queue.